# Shift the address in the hex file with Offset

Tags: compiling, embedded, binary, hex, hexdump

I want to update the hexfile start address with offset. For example, i have a hex file name **abc.hex** and start with address 0x0000 to 0xFFFF. But I want to shift the context in the hexfile to the address 0x1FFFF.
How Can we do this in linux with tool like hexdump or xxd?

Comment: What's the exact format of the file? Every line includes only a string address in hexa format? Starts with the address? Binary? Please provide a short example.

Comment: have you considered investigating the options available to you in `hexdump` and `xxd` - `man` pages contain so called *documentation*